# Scrollmagic- Background colors are not changing properly on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollmagic

I have a issue here with scrollmagic as I am trying to create a demo of natural section wipes in scrollmagic and there I got this above mentioned problem.
Looks like I got something wrong in querySelector but I don't know what I did wrong here

HTML

```
<div class="container-wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="scroller-content">
        <div class="row custom-row">
            <section class="panel red">
                <div class="cover">
                    <strong>One</strong>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row custom-row">
            <section class="panel green">
                <div class="cover">
                    <strong>Two</strong>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row custom-row">
            <section class="panel blue">
                <div class="cover">
                    <strong>Three</strong>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row custom-row">
            <section class="panel orange">
                <div class="cover">
                    <strong>Four</strong>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
    .panel {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 3rem 4rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .red {
        background: #ef5350;
    }

    .green {
        background: #7CB342;
    }

    .blue {
        background: #42A5F5;
    }

    .orange {
        background: #FB8C00;
    }
    .custom-row {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .cover {
        margin: 13rem;
        padding: 13rem;
        top: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
        globalSceneOptions: {
            triggerHook: 'onLeave'
        }
    });


    var slides = document.querySelectorAll("section.panel");


    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: slides[i]
        })
            .setPin(slides[i])
            .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
            .addTo(controller);
    }
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmt_bhavik/u60gj9hc/) for the code help me to figure what where I went wrong with the flow?

Comment: anyone here for suggestion?

Comment: It is unclear what effect you want to create? You want to create color panels scrolling in view? Then you can simply use HTML. Or do you want the background color to change color after x pxs?

Comment: I want to use basic section-swipe of scrollmagic http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/section_wipes_natural.html

Comment: Works fine if I remove the wrapping divs. Just style the sections instead of wrapping them in divs.

Comment: but for a website I need to put wrappers pls suggest whats wrong in my code?

Comment: anybody has answer for this problem with specified condition ??

Comment: Why exactly do you need the divs around it?

Comment: because I want to build responsive design

Comment: What happens if you remove the "sections" and just add the panel classes to the divs? That should work equally well. You'll have to change document.querySelectorAll("section.panel"); to document.querySelectorAll(".panel"); in the JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "sections" and add the panel classes to the divs. That should work equally well. You'll have to change document.querySelectorAll("section.panel"); to document.querySelectorAll("div.panel"); in the JS code. That's all.

```js
$(function() { // wait for document ready
  // init
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {
      triggerHook: 'onLeave'
    }
  });

  // get all slides
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll("div.panel");

  // create scene for every slide
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: slides[i]
      })
      .setPin(slides[i])
      .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
      .addTo(controller);
  }
});
```

```css
.panel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3rem 4rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red {
  background: #ef5350;
}

.green {
  background: #7CB342;
}

.blue {
  background: #42A5F5;
}

.orange {
  background: #FB8C00;
}

.custom-row {
  text-align: center;
}

.cover {
  margin: 13rem;
  padding: 13rem;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="scroller-content">
      <div class="row custom-row panel red">
        <div class="cover">
          <strong>One</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row custom-row panel green">
        <div class="cover">
          <strong>Two</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row custom-row panel blue">
        <div class="cover">
          <strong>Three</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row custom-row panel orange">
        <div class="cover">
          <strong>Four</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or check the fiddle, the snippet seems to have issues with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/u60gj9hc/1/